# .mov file will play in browser, but not in native MediaPlayer app

Tags: android, video, webview, media-player, mov

I am launching the MediaPlayer to play a .mov file that is being passed into the MediaPlayer as a Uri (which is standard).  However, it is telling me that it cannot play the file.  However, if I put this same link on the web, and the click the link to launch the movie (while in my Android browser) the video plays no problem.  However, I can't get the WebView to play it with the Video tag despite all my efforts.

So here is my question, what magic is taking place that allows an android browser app to take a .html url which contains a link to play a video and play it?  If I load the same url in a WebView, or try to pass the video url into the mediaplayer, it is a no go.  The format of the video is .mov.

Thanks in advance to everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android browser and WebView are very different, WebView is very barebones as it was designed expecting people to use it for very basic showing html webpages. WebView by default has no plugins enabled, no javascript enabled and so on and so on. Never expect that because something works in the browser that it will work in a WebView.

Now in regards to how the media is handled. The Browser has extra features set up to strip the video source from the page and launch it in the native player most of the time. This functionality is not built into WebView. And the native player is very picky about what needs to passed into it as a URI to be able to play it.

Hope that helps,
Stevy888

Comment: Hey Stevy.  Yes I enabled many of WebView functionalities that you spoke of to no avail.  I have been able to pass the Uri to the MediaPlayer and have it work, but was hoping for a video tag solution.  Thanks for your input/ :)

Comment: I don't think a video tag solution will work. As far as my understanding goes the only video format supported by the video tag for mobile devices is .mp4 here is a link that says only .mp4 works on android: https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/googlehtml5_ads

Comment: I'm not sure if a complete answer exists to my question given all the possible variables, but regardless your input has helped steer me away from the Video tag and back towards the MediaPlayer (which after an Eclipse clean project is now playing my .mov link).  Thanks.